# How to mock pyplot.show in python (to prevent showing plots)

Tags: python, unit-testing, matplotlib, mocking, python-unittest

I want to assert that matplotlib.pyplot.show was called in one of my class's methods, but I don't want the method to actually call show() and plot on an external window during the unit test. No matter how I try to mock matplotlib, it doesn't seem to work. I'll list the important parts of my code below:

```
#In Model Test Class:
import Model
import matplotlib
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class Model_Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('matplotlib.pyplot')
    def test_plot_data(self, mock_pyplot):
        model = Model()
        model.plot_data()
        mock_pyplot.show.assert_called_once()
```

---

```
#In Model Class:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

class Model(object):
    ... # (__init__ and other methods)
    def plot_data(self):
        self.dataframe.plot(y=self.dataframe.columns, subplots=False, figsize=(15, 8), fontsize=12)
        plt.title('Data for Model Version: ' + self.version, fontsize=20)
        plt.xlabel('timestamp', fontsize=12)
        plt.ylabel('value', fontsize=12)
        plt.show()
```

I also tried setting a return value for mock_plot.show. When I use the debugger, matplotlib within the Model class is not propagated with a Mock object, so I am unsure how to mock the matplotlib module or its member functions. Is it possible to mock matplotlib?

Any ideas for how to properly mock matplotlib in unit tests (mainly to prevent displaying plots)?

EDIT: I was able to get it to work by changing the patch decoration to 
`@patch('matplotlib.pyplot.show')`, 
but I'm still unsure why this worked and my previous attempt didn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `patch`, the `matplotlib` module is patched in-memory so any *new* attempts to access it's child element `pyplot` will reference the mock. However, the module that houses `Model` already has a direct reference to `matplotlib.pyplot`; it obtained that reference when you imported it. It won't go through the patched `matplotlib` module again. When you patch `show` directly, `patch` will instead modify the shared `pyplot` module.

We can illustrate this by also obtaining a direct reference to the original `show` function on module load:

```
# bla.py
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

show = plt.show

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(type(plt))
        print(type(plt.show))
        print(type(show))
```

Python console:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> from bla import A
>>> with patch('matplotlib.pyplot') as p:
...   A()
... 
<class 'module'>
<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
<bla.A object at 0x7f232b98a400>
>>> with patch('matplotlib.pyplot.show') as p:
...   A()
... 
<class 'module'>
<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>
<class 'function'>
<bla.A object at 0x7f232b98d550>
```

You'll note that the reference to `show` that we obtained in the `bla` module remains un-mocked.

Comment: This is extremely helpful info for mocks in general in python. I hadn't considered that the un-mocked reference was established at import time, prior to the patch. Thanks!